# How to download file from external link for users in php

Tags: php

I am running a site for image hosting, It has a function to download images for users if they like. But download does not work at all. It give me it is a invalid image. But the size which I download is same as I have on my site, Here is my code, can any body help

```
<?php
 function get_remote_size($url) {
       $headers = get_headers($url, 1);
       if (isset($headers['Content-Length'])) return $headers['Content-Length'];
       if (isset($headers['Content-length'])) return $headers['Content-length'];

       $c = curl_init();

       curl_setopt_array($c, array(
            CURLOPT_URL => $url,
            CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
            CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array('User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; U;  Intel Mac OS X 10.5; en-US; rv:1.9.1.3) Gecko/20090824 Firefox/3.5.3'),
       ));

       curl_exec($c);
       return curl_getinfo($c, CURLINFO_SIZE_DOWNLOAD);
  }

  $url = 'http://localhost/ds.jpg';
  $name = 'Beezfeed.jpg';
  // Fetch and serve
  function do_the_download($url,$name) {
      header('Pragma: public');     // required
      header('Expires: 0');     // no cache
      header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0');
      header('Last-Modified: '.gmdate ('D, d M Y H:i:s', filemtime($url)).' GMT');
      header('Cache-Control: private',false);
      header('Content-Type: image/jpg');
      header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.$name.'"');
      header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
      header('Content-Length: '. get_remote_size($url) );
      header('Connection: close');
      readfileChunked( $url );
  }


 if(isset($_POST["downloadfile"])) {
     do_the_download($url,$name);
 }

 function readfileChunked($filename, $retbytes=true){
     $chunksize = 1*(1024*1024);
     $buffer = '';
     $cnt = 0;
     $handle = fopen($filename, 'rb');

     if ($handle === false) {
         return false;
     }

     while (!feof($handle)) {
         $buffer = fread($handle, $chunksize);
         echo $buffer;
         ob_flush();
         flush();
         if ($retbytes) {
             $cnt += strlen($buffer);
         }
     }

     $status = fclose($handle);

     if ($retbytes && $status) {
         return $cnt; // return num. bytes delivered like readfile()  does.
     }

     return $status;
 }
       ?>
       <form method="POST">
        <input type="submit" value="DOWNLOAD FILE" name="downloadfile"/>
      </form>
```

I am just giving a raw code, without css and other things to make site beautiful. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two things to try:

1) Take out the line which sets the Last-Modified header. When I tried this, I got a warning from that line, though perhaps under certain circumstances it would work. If you really need the modified time, you can probably get it by knowing the actual file path.

2) Add `die()` after `readfileChunked( $url );`. You need to prevent the form html from appearing at the bottom of the image data.

Comment: @kumar I did both the things told. i.e. added the die() and removed last modified header, but it still is nor working. Can you tell me how did you make your code working, I also want to download images and want to use your code. Thanks